# How to use flatMap for flatten one component of a tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a tuple like.. `(a, list(b,c,d))`. I want the output like

```
(a,b)
(a,c)
(a,d)
```

I am trying to use flatMap for this but not getting any success. Even map is not helping in this case.

Input Data :

```
Chap01:Spark is an emerging technology
Chap01:You can easily learn Spark
Chap02:Hadoop is a Bigdata technology
Chap02:You can easily learn Spark and Hadoop
```

Code:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile("C:\\wc_input.txt")

val chapters = rawData.map(line => (line.split(":")(0), line.split(":")(1)))

val chapWords = chapters.flatMap(a => (a._1, a._2.split(" ")))
```

Comment: `val chapWords = chapters.flatMap { case(a, b)  => b.split(" ").map(word => a -> word) }`. The problem is that **flatMap** expects a **collection** but you are passing it a tuple, so you need to map the collection to create a collection of tuples.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez : Thanks for quick resolution. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario can be easily handled by **flatMapValues** methods in RDD. It works only on values of a pair RDD keeping the key same.

Answer (score 2):

You could map over the second element of the tuple:

```
val t = ('a', List('b','c','d'))
val res = t._2.map((t._1, _))
```

The snipped above resolves to:

```
res: List[(Char, Char)] = List((a,b), (a,c), (a,d))
```